# React, Getting TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance when using global state with Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to use context for accessing state globally but get the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

I tried to solve the problem with adapting the use of context from this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64456948/19099829).

**File from which I wanna get state from:**

```js
const test = () => {
  const [selectedValueRound, setSelectedValueRound] = useState("10 rounds");
  return (
    <View>
      <RoundContext.Provider
        value={[selectedValueRound, setSelectedValueRound]}
      >
        <View>
          <Picker
            selectedValue={selectedValueRound}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              setSelectedValueRound(itemValue)
            }
          >
            <Picker.Item label="1 round" value="0"></Picker.Item>
            <Picker.Item label="2 rounds" value="1"></Picker.Item>
          </Picker>
        </View>
      </RoundContext.Provider>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**File for context:**

```js
export const RoundContext = createContext(false);
```

**File where I try to call context and error appears:**

```js
const SomeFile = () => {
  const [selectedValueRound, setSelectedValueRound] = useContext(RoundContext);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{selectedValueRound}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
export default SomeFile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you wrap `SomeFile` inside `RoundContext.Provider`, as for now, it seems like you are not. Only wrapped components inside the `Provider` can consume a `context`.

Also, make sure that every React component starts with a capital letter, `Test` instead of `test`. Like this:

```
const Test = () => {
  const [selectedValueRound, setSelectedValueRound] = useState("10 rounds");
  return (
    <View>
      <RoundContext.Provider
        value={[selectedValueRound, setSelectedValueRound]}
      >
        <View>
          <Picker
            selectedValue={selectedValueRound}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              setSelectedValueRound(itemValue)
            }
          >
            <Picker.Item label="1 round" value="0"></Picker.Item>
            <Picker.Item label="2 rounds" value="1"></Picker.Item>
          </Picker>
        </View>
        <SomeFile/>
      </RoundContext.Provider>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Test is actually my home page and some file is a page which opens op when a button is clicked. I have a stack file which contains the navigation container who contains every file. I implemented there now `RoundContext.Provider` and it works.

Comment: Yeah that's the key, only wrapped components inside the provider can consume the context. Glad it worked out :)